# How to display the contents of a list into a DataGridView in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

My problem is very simple. I am making a Calendar for a school project. I need to add certain properties to a list of objects in order to save an event to the calendar.  I have managed to add things to the list, but I have not found a way to display all the events of the list in Winforms. My professor suggested I use a DataGridView to display the contents of the list. 
Can someone show me how I can Bind the objects in my list to a DataGridView, and whenever I add something to the list it also adds it to the grid? This would be much appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static void addEvent(string eventDate, string eventTitle, string eventInfo)
    {
        Event Event = new Event();
        Event.eventDate = eventDate;
        Event.eventDate = eventTitle;
        Event.eventInfo = eventInfo;
        events.Add(Event);
    }

}


class Event
{
    public string eventDate { get; set; }
    public string eventTitle { get; set; }
    public string eventInfo { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Bind your DataGridView to a BindingList instead.

Code:

```
public static void addEvent(string eventDate, string eventTitle, string eventInfo)
    {
        Event Event = new Event();
        Event.eventDate = eventDate;
        Event.eventDate = eventTitle;
        Event.eventInfo = eventInfo;
        events.Add(Event);
        var bindinglist = new BindingList<Event>(events);
        var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
        grid.DataSource = source;

    }
```

Comment: OK thanks, but how can I make this work with my Program.CS class and my Form.cs class.....My data GridView1 is not in the scpoe of my program.cs class. And lastly, I want the Listbox to only show the EVENT TITLE...Help on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do anything special:

```
 Event event= new Event();
    event.eventDate = eventDate;
    event.eventDate = eventTitle;
    event.eventInfo = eventInfo;
    events.Add(event);
DataGridView1.DataSource = events;
```

But verify that your Event class is defined as public class

Comment: OK thanks, but how can I make this work with my Program.CS class and my Form.cs class.....My data GridView1 is not in the scpoe of my program.cs class. And lastly, I want the Listbox to only show the EVENT TITLE...Help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: Why you have to do it in Programm class and not in the Form class? Open Form designer, add your DataGridView. On Form's OnLoad event handler, set your list as data source...

Comment: The goal of Programm class is to Start your winForm application. Do your work in the Form!

Comment: this does not work. you cannot display the contents of a list in a datagridview without transforming the list into a different type of object.